# Given a metric space $(X,\rho)$, prove that $|\rho(x,z)-\rho(y,u)|\leq{\rho(x,y)+\rho(z,u)}$ for $x, y, z, u\in{X}$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Obviously it is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I'm considering the quadrilateral inequality but so far it has not been helpful. Can anyone give me direction on how to verify $|\rho(x,z)-\rho(y,u)|\leq{\rho(x,y)+\rho(z,u)}$  for $x, y, z, u\in{X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\rho(x,z)\leq\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,u)+\rho(u,z)\\
\rho(y,u)\leq\rho(y,x)+\rho(x,z)+\rho(z,u)
$$

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @user121087, since you are new here I want to tell you that you can vote for questions and answers and even more accept answers to your questions

Comment: Is this an obvious extension of the triangle inequality?

Comment: @MathStudent1324, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show:

$\rho(x,z)-\rho(y,u) \leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(z,u)$
and $-\rho(x,z)+\rho(y,u) \leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(z,u)$. Now do the "obvious" trick of "changing sides, and using the triangle inequality.